# Restarting a pm2 app selected by user in node.js using pm2 api

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

how do we restart a pm2 application from node.js using the pm2 api when there's a bunch of other apps in a list, and the user can choose which app to restart?
-currentInfo being the thing that has the information about the process.

```
function restart(id) {
    for (const elem of currentInfo) {
        if (elem.pm_id == id) {
            pm2.restart(elem.name, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log("app is restarted");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will restart the pm2 app with specific id (as a parameter to the function) I hope this will solve your problem.

```
function restartPm2(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pm2.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) reject(err)
            pm2.list((err, list) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                for (const iterator of list) {
                    if (iterator.pm_id == id) {
                        pm2.restart(iterator.name, function (err) {
                            if (err) reject(err)
                            resolve("app is restarted");
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

restartPm2(0).then(i => {
    console.log(i);
    pm2.disconnect()
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    pm2.disconnect()
})
```

where 0 is the app id